# None hover effect?

Tags: html, css

I have taken 2 div: When I hover to .box1, .box2 will move from bottom to top; when I don't, .box2 will be invisible immediately, but I want .box2 moving slowly from the top to bottom then invisible, how can I do that?

```css
    .box1 {
     width: 200px;
     height: 200px;
     background-color: red;
     position: relative;
     z-index: 2;
     cursor: pointer;
    }
    .box2 {
     width: 200px;
     height: 200px;
     background: rgba(54, 25, 25, .5);
     position: absolute;
     top: 200px;
     z-index: 1;
     visibility: hidden;
    }
    .box1:hover .box2{
     transition: all 1s;
     visibility: visible;
     top: 0;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="box1">
        Content in box1
     <div class="box2">Content in box2</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: 2 issues .. transition need to be on the element not the hover state and you cannot animate the visibility, so even this won't fix the issue --> so consider opacity instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a transition for box-2. If you add an `overflow: hidden`  for box-1 this will help you to prevent overflowing box-2

```css
.box1 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
overflow: hidden
}
.box2 {
transition: all 1s;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: rgba(54, 25, 25, .5);
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    z-index: 1;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.box1:hover .box2{
    visibility: visible;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
    Content in box1
    <div class="box2">Content in box2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not the ideal way to animate and hide elements (Idealy for smooth transition try using jQuery) but hope this will help you out.

Remove `transition` from the hover state and add it to the main style of `.box2`

Check out the snippet for better understanding.

```css
.box1 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.box2 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: rgba(54, 25, 25, .5);
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    z-index: 1;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: all 1s;
}
.box1:hover .box2{
    visibility: visible;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
    Content in box1
    <div class="box2">Content in box2</div>
</div>
```

Hope this help

Comment: He want hide box2 after animation. In your example box2 just hide without animation

Comment: Are you serious?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Confused with another property